# How to use Nsubstitue for method with different arguments and return values?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

For unit testing I am using `NSubstitue` to stub my repository method (say `IRepo.GetOrder(orderId)`) I am able to stub this for one specific argument like :

```
IRepo RepoSub = Substitute.For<IRepo>();
Order ord = new Order{/*...*/}
RepoSub.GetOrder(Arg.Is<int>(123)).ReturnsForAnyArgs(ord);
```

However BL method I am testing makes use of `Repository` for multiple Order Ids in array passed as an i/p parameter to that BL method (`int[] orderIds`). I am not sure how can I use `NSubstitue` for varying arguments in `RepoSub` `GetOrder`. I tried figuring out in Nsubstitue document, but no luck.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to vary the `Order` return value, you have to configure your stub/mock to return a wellknown `Order` instance for each separate `orderId` value.

```
var order1 = new Order { Id = 1 };
var order2 = new Order { Id = 2 };
var order3 = new Order { Id = 3 };
IRepo repoSub = Substitute.For<IRepo>();

repoSub.GetOrder(1).Returns(order1);
repoSub.GetOrder(2).Returns(order2);
repoSub.GetOrder(3).Returns(order3);

var o3 = repoSub.GetOrder(3); // order3
var o2 = repoSub.GetOrder(2); // order2
var o1 = repoSub.GetOrder(1); // order1
```

Comment: I doubt this would help to actually test scenario. with this i might end up returning same order for all passed in order Ids as I/p, isn't it ?

Comment: Indeed, that wasn't clear for me from the question.

Comment: I updated my answer in order to vary the returned `Order` instance.

Comment: ok. thx!! so when GetOrder is called with say `OrderId` 1 which order it will return ?

Comment: Actually am expecting something like when Id =1, stubbed return should return Order1..for Id=2 it should return Order2 and so on..

Comment: Are you sure it will work because I remember checking this and it end up like i get result only for ID=3 as last one kind of overrides previous two stubs

Comment: I'm possitive; please update your question with the code you are using if this doesn't give the expected result for you,

Comment: thanks, that worked. actually i was doing one more mistake in my original post. instead of using `Return(..)` i was using `ReturnsForAnyArgs(..)`